# Select from table where clause from array from another table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to insert a failsafe into a code to prevent them from going a step further, and I've been scratching my head for a while now. I am able to put something into an array, but I am not able to get the items from the array to match the second select query. I only get Array instead of the value from the item.

My first select query is this:

```
$datohenter3 = "select DATE_FORMAT(datotid, '%Y.%m.%d') AS dato from gramorapport34 group by dato order by dato asc";
$hentdatoer = $db->query($datohenter3);

$periodedatoer = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= $db->affected_rows; $x++) {
    $periodedatoer[] = $hentdatoer->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Then I want to match the values from this array with my next select query:

```
$rapportdatoer = "select fradato, tildato from gramorapportlogg WHERE  fradato IN('".$periodedatoer."') OR tildato IN('".$periodedatoer."')";
$rapportdatoeksist = $db->query($rapportdatoer);
if ( !$rapporteksist ) die('Database Error: '.$db->error);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rapportdatoeksist))
     {
        print_r($row);
     }
```

The errors I am getting are:

> Notice: Array to string conversion for the second select
>
> Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' fradato IN('Array') OR tildato IN('Array')' at line 1

I'm not an expert in JOIN SELECT queries. This is using MariaDB 10.3.12 with PHP7.2

var_dump available at: https://www.lokalradio.no/rapport/gramo/datohenttest.php

Comment: `$periodedatoer` is an array - choose the field you want to insert in the second query and use `implode(",", $periodedatoer)`

Comment: The reason I'm doing DATE_FORMAT on the first select query is because I want to santitize the dato output to the same format as the dato format in the other table.

Comment: If i do this: `$rapportdato=implode(",", $periodedatoer);` and then in the second query use IN('".$rapportdato."') I get the same error, and it's only able to put in Array in the select query. I want to put the dato from array I get.

Comment: Try `$rapportdato=implode("','", $periodedatoer);` (notice the `'` in the `implode`). And then in the `SELECT`

Comment: This line `$rapportdatoer = "select fradato, tildato from gramorapportlogg WHERE lokalradio=$radiokanal AND fradato IN('". implode("','", $periodedatoer) ."') OR tildato IN('". implode("','", $periodedatoer) ."')";` still gives the array to string conversion error.

Comment: Can you please share the `$periodedatoer` contains? `var dump`?

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `$periodedatoer` is an array of array. Each element inside has 1 key of `dato` (as you `var_dump` displays).

So use [array-column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the values and then `implode` as:

```
$rapportdato = implode("','", array_column($periodedatoer, "dato"));
```

Now you can use `$rapportdato` in your second query as:

```
$rapportdatoer = "select fradato, tildato from gramorapportlogg WHERE  fradato IN('" . $rapportdato . "') OR tildato IN('" . $rapportdato . "')";
```